# App Engine not loading queue.xml

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

I have a multi-module style Google App Engine App. It has a main Java Enterprise Project (eap), which references 3 Dynamic Web Projects. All works great.

Except task queues.. I am trying to create my own custom taskqueue. I created a WEB-INF folder in my EAP project, next to the META-INF folder.. And I created a queue.xml file there (pasted below) .

When I go to the Administrator area of cloud.google.com and click Task Queues, I only see the 'default' queue, my push queue is not there..

Upon deployment, I see no errors, just:

```
INFO: Successfully processed C:/!zebrastues/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/zebrasear/zebras-feeder.war\WEB-INF/queue.xml
```

My queue.xml (in a WEB-INF folder in my EAP, also added into the WEB-INF folder of my dynamic web projects, but it is ignored there).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queue-entries>
  <queue>
    <name>feedq</name>
    <rate>1/s</rate>  
  </queue>
</queue-entries>
```

Comment: You mean creating WEB-INF at the level as src/META-INF? Try to put the queue.xml file where your appengine-web.xml file is.

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for your help. I actually have three different appengine-web.xml files. It is a multi-module EAP/EAR setup. I did copy the queue.xml into the seperate WEB-INF folders where the appengine-web.xml files are, but still no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to app engine modules [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Configuration), optional configuration files like queue.xml and datastore-indexes.xml apply to all modules and should be placed in the WEB-INF directory that contains the **default** module.